# How to load images in unity with button click

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to load images in unity with button click.

What I'm trying to do is I will have a list of images in a folder. And with a next and previous button all images will be viewed one after one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy.

Just instantiate a variable from **Texture2D** and call its **LoadImage** method. like this:

```
var T = new Texture2D(1, 1);
T.LoadImage("Address to your image");
```

Then you can assign the texture **T** to a **RawImage** like this:

```
var RI = GetComponent<RawImage>();
RI.texture = T;
```

Comment: What if I want to load next image.

Comment: And what to put in "address to your image" as it is in a folder called "Assets".

Comment: You must create a folder named **StreamingAssets** inside **Assets** folder and put your images in **StreamingAssets**. Then using `Application.streamingAssetsPath` method you can access the folder and your images.